# Node Inspector: Running Code - Not Just Stepping Through

Tags: debugging, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector, node-inspector

### What I want

I want to be able to **run** a whole script in `node` during debugging with `node-inspector` and Web Inspector. - I **don't** want to **step through** the individual JavaScript calls.

### What I did

*(My PowerShell Instructions)*

```
PS C:\Users\JK> node-inspector
   info  - socket.io started
visit http://0.0.0.0:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging
...

==[In another PowerShell instance:]==

PS %> node —debug-brk myscript.js
debugger listening on port 5858
```

### Why I want that

I'm writing a node script. In this script I `console.log` a lot of objects in order to be able to explore them during the debugging process. But the simple static textual console output isn't really nice - You can't fold and expand your object's properties or get the source code of a function:

*(For Example)*

```
{ [Function: Xy]
  a: [Function],
  b: 8.2,
  c: [Function],
  d: [Circular],
  e: '2011-11-11' }
```

So I decided to use Web Inspector with `node-inspector` in order to get a good object browse experience (because of Web Inspector's nice output formatting).

### Why I Don't Step Through

*(Structure of My Script)*

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('myfile', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    //My Script...

    console.log(something);
});
```

1. The `console.log()` calls are executed in a callback function of
   `require('fs').readFile()`. I won't get there just with "normal"
   steps.
2. It's simply boring the click the *Step* buttons again and again.

### My Questions

- Is there a possibility to run a script without stepping through using the following Web Inspector user interface? **(I don't want to use `node —debug myscript.js` instead of `node —debug-brk myscript.js` because then Inspector throws `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  Is node running with --debug port 5858?` because the script runs too fast)**

*(Web Inspector Interface)*
[image: Web Inspector Interface]

- Or is there at least **any other way** to do what I described above (in the *Why I want that* section).

Thanks. -
(I hope it's clear what I wanted to ask. - Please write a comment if it isn't.)

Comment: I would like to browse objects in Chrome Inspector too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options.

Using `--debug-brk`:

1. Start your script, let it stop on the first line.

   In the Script pane, click the line number inside the callback (line
   4 in this
       example).

   Click "Continue" (the "|> icon above the right-hand panel).

Using `--debug`:

1. Add the line `debugger;` to your callback. This will stop the
   debugger at that point. Click "|>" when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. - After playing around with `npm` I got `node-inspector` to work correctly when clicking *Continue*. - I don't know why, but node doesn't stop execution on `debugger;`.

Comment: There are certain execution contexts I've encountered where web inspector hasn't loaded the source file in time to set the breakpoint before the file's already been executed. I usually take the safe route and set --debug-brk on the command line, then step between points where I know new files are getting loaded. Still, sounds like you're on the right track. Keep playing with it!